# remove content of directory in elegant way

Tags: shell, directory, rm, cwd

I would like to remove all content of the current working directory.
How to do it in efficient and elegant way?

I have several files, directories and some of them starts with dot, like:

```
touch .abc; touch abcd ; mkdir foobar; touch "file name" "#"
```

I am looking for posix compatible, elegant solution, to make this directory empty.
I will post some of my ideas, but none of them are perfect.

Comment: ``d=$(basename `pwd`); cd .. && rm -rf ./${d} && mkdir ${d} && cd -``

Comment: @devnull: fails if you don't have perms to remove CWD.

Comment: It was assumed that you have perms on the directory.  Nevertheless, this should work regardless ``d=$(basename `pwd`); cd .. && mktemp -p ./${d} && rm -rf ./${d} && mkdir ${d} && cd -``

Comment: Delete including subdirs?

Answer (score 6):

```
rm -rf -- * .*
```

This is portable and works, but it's ugly, because except with `zsh`, it issues warnings:

```
rm: cannot remove directory: `.'
rm: cannot remove directory: `..'
```

Comment: Yeah, you can adapt with stuff like `[^.]` but then you'll have other problems (like folders named `..abc`); so, I doubt you can get rid of these nasty warnings. It's not a "clean" option, but it works.

Comment: @TomWijsman, `[^.]` is not POSIX, `[!.]` is.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: If you need POSIX, then convert the syntax, I don't care...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name \. -exec rm -rf \{\} ;
```

Comment: `-maxdepth` and `-not` are not posix. `!` is.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly:

```
rm -rf -- * .[!.]* ..?*
```

That one could fail if the list of files it too big, this one wouldn't:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
```

With `zsh`:

```
rm -rf -- *(D)
```

Comment: Stéphane, you rock!

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I found is to:

```
find . -delete
```

however, -delete predicate is risky (see man) and I don't like to use it.

**Update:**

I don't like `-delete` predicate because it can cause a disaster when used by someone not familiar with the details of find's logic. For example:

```
find . -delete -name '*.bak'  # DO NOT DO IT!!!
```

Someone may expect such call to remove only '*.bak' files, but it is exact equivalent to `find . -delete`.

Comment: This should be the best option; I don't see why it would be risky, it's logic to put it at the end and you can first run it without that to see what it would delete.

Comment: @TomWijsman in this case `-delete` is fine, but in general `-delete` is risky, this is why I don't like it.

Comment: `-delete`  is not POSIX.

Comment: What about `-exec rm -rf {} \;`?

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
 rm -rf * .[a-z]* .[A-Z]* .[0-9]*
```

will that work ? or you have other file name patterns to match as well ?

Comment: in posix filesystem, almost any character can be in the filename. Try `touch '#'`.

Comment: Restricting to certain characters isn't really reliable; you're missing the often used `.` and `-` for instance, but even including these you may come across a `_` or other less frequent characters.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to remember value of `pwd`, `cd ..`, `rm -rf` the directory and recreate the directory. This is also ugly for many reasons.

*BTW, please do not down-vote. Comment if needed.*

Answer (score 0):

First delete files, then empty directories:

```
find . -type f -exec rm \{\} \;
find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir \{\} \;
```

Comment: this "trivial task" is getting crazy... ;-)

Comment: `-empty` is not POSIX. `-type f` is for regular files only. You would miss other types of files like symlinks, sockets, pipes, doors, devices... Use `! -type d` instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
rm -rf .
```

This of course does not work at all, however this:

```
rm -rf -- "$PWD"
```

removes CWD, and we end up within nonexisting directory. This is very ugly.

*BTW, please do not down-vote. Comment if needed.*

Comment: Well, this does not remove the "content" of a directory.

Comment: @TomWijsman. Agree. This is why it would need recreation of the directory. Yet another ugly solution...